# Oracle PL / SQL printing each letter of a string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to print out the letters of the word 'Hello' each on its own , I wrote this :

```
Declare
c1 Number:=1;
c2 Varchar2(5);
begin
for c1 in 1..5
loop
select substr('Hello' , c1 , 1 ) into c2 from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(c2);
end loop;
end;
```

but it skips the first two letter and the out is

```
l
l
o
```

any ideas what might be the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you can replace the `select into` into a simple assignment like `c2 := substr('Hello' , c1 , 1 );`.  Apart from that, I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Is the input string Unicode or some non-ASCII?

Comment: Also your declaration of `c1` is redundant as the loop variable has scope precedence; and your `c2` only needs to be a single character; but those wouldn't break it either. Works as you'd expect for me. How are you running it?

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing all of your output? Are you restricting the number of lines displayed in whatever tool you're using?

Comment: I replaced the select into statement as  GolezTrol mentioned and it's working now , to be honest I'm still wondering what was the problem with my code , apart of the minor mistakes you guys mentioned it should have worked .

Comment: Mark Leiber , yeah I thought of that also , still I scrolled up and down that was the only output.

Comment: IN your original code what happens if you change the varchar size of c2?

Comment: @Mihai Nothing happens , the same output.

Comment: What version of oracle?Put it in as a tag

Comment: Posted code outputs five rows for me.  It's pretty hard to diagnose a problem we can't reproduce.

Comment: Works fine on 11.2.0.4 EE.

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no need for a `select`. `c2 := substr('Hello' , c1 , 1 ):` will work just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better to have Loop end limit  `For i in 1..v_length` This way you do not have to change the `Loop` limit each time you run.

```
 Create or replace procedure print_string( IN_string IN varchar2 )
AS
v_length number(10);
v_out varchar2(20);
Begin
v_length := length(IN_string);
for i in 1..v_length
Loop
v_out  := substr(IN_string,i,1) ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_out);
End loop;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Text printed: ' || IN_string);
End;
 -- Procedure created.

BEGIN
print_string('Hello');
END;


-- Output:

H
e
l
l
o
Text printed: Hello

Statement processed.
```

Answer (score 5):

It can be done in a single select too:

```
SQL> select substr('hello', level, 1) Letter
     from dual
     connect by level <= length('hello');

L
-
h
e
l
l
o

SQL>
```

EDIT: If you'd like to prompt for a word:

```
set verify off

ACCEPT word CHAR PROMPT 'Enter the word >';

select substr('&&word', level, 1) Letters
    from dual
    connect by level <= length('&&word');
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you have written is right.

```
Declare
c1 Number:=1;
c2 Varchar2(5);
begin
for c1 in 1..5
loop
select substr('Hello' , c1 , 1 ) into c2 from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(c2);
end LOOP;
end;
```

output:-

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

Answer (score 0):

select substr('hello', level, 1) Letter
2  from dual
3  connect by level <= length('hello');

in the above case, string is given during query writing. what to do when string has to be given as an input?
eg.   input :- NARESH

```
 output :- N
           A
           R
           E
           S
           H
```

Comment: See the edit to my answer above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your script:

```
declare
    c1 number := 1;
    c2 varchar2(5);
begin
    for c1 in 1 .. 5 loop
        select substr('Hello', c1, 1) into c2 from dual;
        dbms_output.put_line(c2);
    end loop;
end;
```

Outputs the following:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

All looks fine for me.

What output do you get?