# How to print each letter of a word on its own line using PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

How to print each letter of a word in a column of a table on its own line using PL/SQL? Word is like this "animal"; I want to convert it like:

```
a
n
i
m
a
l
```

using PL/SQL. I am new to PL/SQL. I tried to substr and loop through word. But don't know how to do it.

```
DECLARE
    total integer;
begin
    total := length('animal');
    x :=1
    while 1..total LOOP
    x=x+1;     
    select substr('animal',x,1) from dual

end
```

Comment: Have a look at [the SUBSTR function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#SQLRF06114)

Comment: how to loop it after substr

Comment: Sorry but this all looks a bit "please do my homework" to me!

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995683/oracle-pl-sql-printing-each-letter-of-a-string/30053370#30053370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, I just added some codes to yours not to confuse you.

```
DECLARE
    x integer; /* you forgot to declare x */
    total integer;
    schar CHAR; /* variable holding each char of word */
begin
    total := length('animal');
    x :=1; /* do not miss semicolons */
    while x<=total /* in while loop you must use a condition to check for every iteration.*/
    LOOP   
        schar:=substr('animal',x,1);
        x:=x+1;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(schar); /* print the output */
    END LOOP;
end;
```